# How to wait for asynchronous chrome.storage.local.get() to finish before continuing execution

Tags: asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have two calls to `chrome.storage.local.get()`. I need for these calls to finish before continuing executing the rest of the code (calling `continueCode()` function) for my chrome extension, but I'm not sure how to do this, here is my code.

```js
function getData() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
        if (Object.values(result)[0] != undefined) {
            object1.innerHTML = Object.values(result)[0].val;
        }
    });

    chrome.storage.local.get(['key2'], function(result) {
         if (Object.values(result)[0] != undefined) {
             object2.innerHTML = Object.values(result)[0].val;
         }
    });

    continueCode();
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to wait for both callback function that you pass to `chrome.storage.local.get(..)` to be executed before you call `continueCode()`, also, you can check both storage properties with a single call, here is an example:

```
function getData() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['key', 'key2'], function(result) {
    if (typeof result.key !== 'undefined') {
      object1.innerHTML = result.key.val;
    } 
    if (typeof result.key2 !== 'undefined') {
      object2.innerHTML = result.key2.val;
    } 
    continueCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was having some trouble with storing and getting objects of two different keys, but I'll try this out.

Comment: so `continueCode()` will execute immediately after the if conditionals are checked (and if they are true) and the innerHTML of the object is set, because in my `continueCode()` I get object1 or object2 from the HTML by calling `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz No, `continueCode()` will be executed no matter if the properties are set or not.

Comment: The issue that I'm having is that object1 is a table and I need to remove, add, and sort rows from the table. I need to be able to do this after the object1.innerHTML is set and updated, the issue that I am having is that it removes and adds some rows but won't remove or add some rows that it needs to until after I keep reloading the webpage. Object1 and Object2 are stored before the page unloads. I can add some of my code but I can't add too much since I need to keep the specifications of this project private.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that I am using `chrome.storage.local` and not `chrome.storage.sync`?

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz It is not clear what you're trying to do. I don't think that using `local` instead of `sync` is the problem, you can learn how storage works form the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage), this is just basic javascript, using callback functions and checking an object's properties.

Comment: it's a little difficult to explain what I am trying to do with my chrome extension since I need to keep specifications a secret and it's used for a specific website. But this code does work for trying to get two key-value pairs simultaneously with the chrome.storage API.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `new Promise`, `async/await` to handle this. Let's say that you want to handle `chrome.storage.local.get` synchronously so that `continueCode()` can has the needed data.

Get data:

```js
  const readLocalStorage = async (key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.local.get([key], function (result) {
        if (result[key] === undefined) {
          reject();
        } else {
          resolve(result[key]);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

Main function:

```js
async function getData() {
    let key1 = await readLocalStorage('key1');
    object1.innerHTML = key1;
    let key2 = await readLocalStorage('key1');
    object1.innerHTML = key2;

    continueCode();
}
```

or if you're not familiar with `async/await` behavior. You could wrap those 2 promises into an array and use `Promise.all`, like so:

```js
function getData() {
    const key1 = readLocalStorage('key1');
    const key2 = readLocalStorage('key2');

    Promise.all([key1, key2]).then(values => {
        object1.innerHTML = values[0];
        object2.innerHTML = values[1];

        continueCode();
    });
}
```

Comment: I needed `new Promise`, not just `Promise`.

Comment: `function async getData()` gave me an error. Changing the code to `async function getData()` resolved it

Comment: Getting an "uncaught exception: undefined" error pointing at the very last closing bracket of the getData() function.

Comment: kind of magical with JavaScript's stacktrace right? :D. Just check the brackets and syntax @FMaz

Comment: @ToanQuocHo the issue was that the promise failed (as the first time, the key did not exist in local storage, so the promise failed) and the code did not have a catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#asynchronous-preload-from-storage has an example of getting chrome storage asynchronously. They use the following function. (I modified it to be able to return any top keys)

```
function getAllStorageSyncData(top_key) {
  // Immediately return a promise and start asynchronous work
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Asynchronously fetch all data from storage.sync.
    chrome.storage.local.get(top_key, (items) => {
      // Pass any observed errors down the promise chain.
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      }
      // Pass the data retrieved from storage down the promise chain.
      resolve(items);
    });
  });
}

// It can be called like this:
var obj = await getAllStorageSyncData(['key','key2']);
// obj will have obj.key and obj.key2
```

Put `null` as the top key to return all keys.